# Interpolated string with form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that submits to an API....right now i have a field attribute called

```
 :subject
```

Which is basically the user name

What i want is to be able to add a string to this and say

```
 Hello from :subject
```

right now I have this but it does not work

```
 = f.text_field "Hello #{:subject}"
```

heres my controller

```
  def create
    @contacts = Form.new(params[:contacts])
    @contacts.post_tickets(params[:contacts]) 
  end
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `value` option:

```
= f.text_field :subject, value: "Hello, #{obj.subject}"
```

Comment: i get a undefined local variable or method `obj'

Comment: it just replaces my input field with Hello

Comment: @fotanus - so i did = f.text_field :subject, value: "Hello, #{@contacts.subject}" but all i get in my input field is hello #{@contacts.subject}

Comment: @Ricky Ahn, using single or double quotes?

Comment: @pdobb - double quotes

Comment: so when i do this in the console c = Form.new(subject: 'Ricky', email: 'ricky@email.com', description: 'hello') i get back <Form:0x007fd2610a2428 @config={:api_key=>"dddddddddd", :password=>"X", :url=>"http://website.freshdesk.com/"}, @client=#<Freshdesk:0x007fd2610a6438 @base_url="http://website.freshdesk.com/">, @attributes={:subject=>"Ricky", :email=>"ricky@email.com", :description=>"hello"}>